# python web crawler,when I crawl a URL, the status_code displays 405

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

Recently, I was learning python. When I  use BeautifulSoup and requests to get the html, I get a status that 405. What's more,the soup is wrong. I visited the [URL](http://www.qichacha.com/search?key=%E5%A9%9A%E5%BA%86).

Here is my code:

```
def craw(url):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0'
    headers = {'User_Agent':user_agent,
'Accept':'*/*',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',

'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Host':'www.qichacha.com',
'Referer':'http://www.qichacha.com/search?key=%E5%A9%9A%E5%BA%86',
}
    response = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        print(response.status_code)
        print('ERROR')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    print(soup)
if __name__ == '__main__':
url = r'http://www.qichacha.com/search?key=%E5%A9%9A%E5%BA%86'
s1 = craw(url)
```

the output:

```html
405
ERROR
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-cn">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="a3c0e" name="data-spm"/>
<title>405</title>
<style>
            html, body, div, a, h2, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 微软
雅黑; }
            a { text-decoration: none; color: #3b6ea3;  }
            .container { width: 1000px; margin: auto; color: #696969; }


            .header { padding: 50px 0; }
            .header .message { height: 36px; padding-left: 120px; background: ur
l(https://errors.aliyun.com/images/TB1TpamHpXXXXaJXXXXeB7nYVXX-104-162.png) no-r
epeat 0 -128px; line-height: 36px; }

            .main { padding: 50px 0; background: #f4f5f7; }
            .main img { position: relative; left: 120px; }

            .footer { margin-top: 30px; text-align: right; }
            .footer a { padding: 8px 30px; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px soli
d #4babec; }
            .footer a:hover { opacity: .8; }

            .alert-shadow { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #999; opacity: .5; }
            .alert { display: none; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 50%; w
idth: 600px; margin-left: -300px; padding-bottom: 25px; border: 1px solid #ddd;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); background: #fff; font-size: 14px;
color: #696969; }
            .alert h2 {  margin: 0 2px; padding: 10px 15px 5px 15px; font-size:
14px; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
            .alert a { display: block; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 8px
; width: 30px; height: 20px; text-align: center; }
            .alert p {  padding: 20px 15px; }
        </style>
</head>
<body data-spm="7663354">
<div data-spm="1998410538">
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="message">很抱歉，由于您访问的URL有可能对网站造成安全威胁，您的访问被
阻断。</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<img src="https://errors.aliyun.com/images/TB15QGaHpXXXXXOaXXXXia39XXX-660-117.p
ng"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="container">
<a data-spm-click="gostr=/waf.123.123;locaid=d001;" href="javascript:;" id="repo
rt" target="_blank">误报反馈</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="alert-shadow" id="alertShadow"></div>
<div class="alert" id="alertContainer">
<h2>提示：<a href="javascript:;" id="closeAlert" title="关闭">X</a></h2>
<p>感谢您的反馈，应用防火墙会尽快进行分析和确认。</p>
</div>
<script>
             function show() {

                var g = function(ele) { return document.getElementById(ele); };
                var reportHandle = g('report');
                var alertShadow = g('alertShadow');
                var alertContainer = g('alertContainer');
                var closeAlert = g('closeAlert');

                var own = {};

                own.report = function() {
                    // SPM
                    own.alert();
                };

                own.alert = function() {
                    alertShadow.style.display = 'block';
                    alertContainer.style.display = 'block';
                };

                own.close = function() {
                    alertShadow.style.display = 'none';
                    alertContainer.style.display = 'none';
                };

            };
        </script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://errors.aliyun.com/error.js?s=3" type="text/
javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>



------------------
(program exited with code: 0)

请按任意键继续. . .
```

According to my output, I know that I got soup is not the page I want. But where is the problem? I'm a novice.

Comment: try without header.

Comment: That image tag looks like the image that Cloudflare shows when it blocks something it perceives to be a DOS threat. Did you spam that URL with a lot of requests?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar, I've tried it, but unfortunately it's still wrong.

Comment: @AndyCarlson,I know what you mean,but I don't spam that URL with a lot of request.

Answer (score 1):

I try to deal with the problem.Fortunately,I have solved the problem by use the complete header.

```
 headers = {
'Host':'www.qichacha.com',
'User-Agent':r'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/55.0',
'Accept':'*/*',
'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Referer':'http://www.qichacha.com/',
'Cookie':'use your cookies'
'If-Modified-Since':'Wed, 30 Aug 2017 10:48:38 GMT',
'If-None-Match':'"59a69806-80"',
'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',}
```

Comment: Accept the answer too.

Comment: And post full answer.